# Rails webpacker is not reading app/javascript/images folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpack-dev-server

Using the default configuration of [rails/webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) I could not read a file through the `<%= asset_pack_path 'images/calendar.png' %>` helper in a view.
Reading the [docs](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/assets.md#link-in-your-rails-views) it seems easy to do, but something goes wrong trying access the page:

> Webpacker can't find application.css in /path/manifest.json. Possible causes:
>
> > 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
> >        unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
> > 2. Webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
> > 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
> > 4. Your Webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
> >        Your manifest contains:

Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: did you try to add asset path in resolved_paths:['my-non-default-asset-folder'] in webpacker.yml?

Comment: yes, I did. But running the webpack, the files in folder aren't added at manifest.json

Answer (score 1):

It seems a docs misundertand as the [answer](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/791):

> asset_pack_path only references assets used as pack (i.e. JS packs file) or assets used inside a pack like a font, image or styles referenced that's why it's not present inside manifest.json. asset_pack_path doesn't look inside any folder like rails view helpers for assets.
>
> Perhaps use Rails image_path helper if you want to reference images that’s not used inside packs.

Answer (score 0):

The webpacker documention tells us about using:

```js
require.context('../images', true)
```

in an entrypoint (app/javascript/packs), to include all the images under app/javascript/images into the exported assets.
If you are using webpacker6.pre/beta, [there is currently a bug](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2956) which flattens nested folders, though.